# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished with PostgreSQL 9.1.3 and RoR 3.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, homebrew

I just installed PostgreSQL with homebrew:

```
$ brew install postgresql
```

I installed the pg gem with:

```
 $ gem install pg -- --with-pg-config= '/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf'
```

I changed my app's database.yml to

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: rails_dev
  pool: 5
  username: vise890
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: rails_test
  pool: 5
  username: vise890
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: ddb
  port: 5432
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: admin
```

However, whenever i load any page I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

I can connect to the db with pgAdmin (u:vise890 P:{none}) and i see the databases.

I am doing [example3](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec%3astatic_pages_exercises) from the Ruby on Rails Tutorial

If you want to check the whole thing: [Sample App github branch](https://github.com/vise890/sample_app/tree/postgres)

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, nevermind. I started from scratch and it worked. Here's [the walkthrough](http://peg.gd/2p2) in case you are interested

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Comment: oops.. sorry I'm new! I'll keep it mind for the next time! Cheers